# .NET MAUI iOS splash screen dark image not displayed

Tags: ios, maui, splash-screen

I need to create a splash screen that changes color and image based on dark or light mode. I noticed that the .NET MAUI launch screen does not support changing image based on light or dark mode. So I am now trying to use a native launch screen.

For iOS I am using a LaunchScreen.storboard:

1. I added an imageset with the light and dark images.
2. I set the background color of the LaunchScreen.storboard to systembackground

When I launch the app, the background color of the splash screen is displayed correctly based on the selected appearance **but the image is not **: always the light image is displayed.

Doing the same in a Xamarin.Forms project works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you made sure info.plist does NOT contain key/value pair `UILaunchStoryboardName`/`MauiSplash`? [Maui SplashScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?tabs=ios). In case you were earlier experimenting with Maui's SplashScreen approach, and those got set. I think explicitly add `UILaunchStoryboardName`/`LaunchScreen`, which is yours. (It might do that by default, but since it isn't working, best to add it manually.)

Comment: Yes, the info.plist is set correctly and the correct launch screen is displayed, only the image is not displayed. Doing the same for a Xamarin.Forms project it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official docs [Add a splash screen to a .NET MAUI app project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=ios%22https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=ios%22). On iOS, the splash screen is added to the app package as a storyboard named `MauiSplash.storyboard`, which is set as value of the `UILaunchStoryboardName` key in the app package's `Info.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  ...
  <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
  <string>MauiSplash</string>
  ...
</dict>
</plist>
```

Therefore, you shouldn't set the `UILaunchStoryboardName` key in your `Info.plist` file and you shouldn't add a `LaunchScreen.storyboard` to your app. So you cannot customize splash screen currently by setting the `storyboard`. That said you can design an image including the splash screen images you want to customize, then drag the image into the Resources\Splash folder of your project.

And you can create a feature request at https://github.com/dotnet/maui for customizing splash screen on iOS via `Storyboard` file.

Hopefully this clears that up a little bit.